# Selfhosted asp.net webapi - how to get active directory authentication?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I would like to selfhost asp.net web api 2 within our own window service as it is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Since we use Active Directory in our organization (local AD, not azure) - how would I go about having the user's principal flow to the server side once he accesses the web api (via browser).

I know it works with IIS hosting... but how do I go about it with a self hosted web api?